# Unable to reference netcore2.0 DLL from a V4.6.1 WCF service project

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a WCF service project written in C#, .net framework V4.6.1. I tried to consume the dll of another project in netcore2.0. I got an error message; **Project X targets 'netcoreapp2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v4.6.1**

Comment: Netcore2 is different then net standard 2. You can only reference net standard dlls

Comment: @Matt, thank you for the quick response. What this tells me is that netcore2 is not fully compatible with older .net standards. I urgently need a solution to this problem.

Comment: Could you  just upgrade to a completely net core 2 service or is it a large preexisting wcf service? Is the net core 2 doll something you wrote? If so change the build for it to be net standard 2 and solve any incompatibility issues.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you @Matt, I am currently updating my visual studio. I will change the WCF project to run on net standard and try to consume the netcore dll again. I will provide update when I am done. Thank you once again.

Comment: I am done with VS update but not able to create project with .net standard target framework as it is not displayed on the dropdown list of available target frameworks. Any idea what could be the issue @Matt?

Comment: What is the ultimate problem you are trying to solve? You have to start with a net core or net standard project. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio